# Why do some Facebook User Ids randomly throw a graph exception?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I get Facebook User Ids using the publicly available data on the Facebook graph API. When I query some users, I get the normal public information. However, when I use the same query with different user ids, it returns the follow error:

```
"Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api", 
"type": "GraphMethodException", 
"code": 100
```

I have compiled some examples:

Users that randomly return the error: `10202985968284866`, `10203670229904527`, `10201183468423349`

Users that work fine: `535548246581477`, `10153112866849029`, `618670188244877`, and `934186386626804`

Any ideas why this is?

Comment: Which API version are you using?

Comment: I have come across some ids who can be viewed on the site, but cannot be queried via the API. Someone from Facebook team could have a logical answer like @wizkid

Comment: Latest version 2.2 - this even happens in the Graph API Explorer.

Comment: Where do the user ids come from? If they are not "created" by the same app you're trying to request the info with the request will yield in an error. Also, are you using a User or an App Access Token?

Comment: As Tobi mentioned, you can not a particular user id in more than one application.  All ids are generated on a per app basis and only work for the specific app.  The ids in graph explorer wont work outside it.

Comment: You have to use an access token from the same app as the access token you used to get the user id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the simpler days of v1.0, when the Graph API reported on a user, the id value it provided was a global id number for that Facebook user. These values were “global” in the sense that they could be shared between client applications. In v2.0, all user data provided by the /user endpoint and its children use application-specific ids. These ids are a unique identifier not just of the Facebook user, but of the client-user pair. This mean that you can’t share user ids between applications. (Though Facebook does provide an API for mapping between applications that are part of single organization.)

An important consequence of this fact is that the user ids recognized by the Facebook applications you use for development will not match the ones your production app recognizes. So, if you store your users’ Facebook ids in your database in production, you won’t be able to match up users in that database with data returned from the API in development. That’s annoying!

And there’s no way around it. You’ll just have to query for a few of your friends from the development app and manually overwrite their stored Facebook ids in your development database. This will give you a few exemplars to develop against.